# Are Penny-Farthings Legal to Ride on Public Roads (UK)

Tags: brakes, legal, lighting, penny-farthing

***Are Penny-Farthings legal to ride on public roads in the UK?***

**Note**: For laws regarding riding Penny-Farthings on public roads in other countries-ie "US" or "EU"- please start a new question with the same title and just replace "(UK)" with the "(US)", "(EU)" etc... so things are logically ordered into taxonomies. It will be a tangle otherwise...

Comment: perhaps a better organizational scheme would be to title the questions "Where are PFs legal to ride on public roads?" and then the answers would be e.g., "In the UK, they are legal...", "in <these parts of the EU> they are legal according to..."

Comment: I see "6" up votes for @PaulH's suggestion so far, which BTW sounds a very good one. If I see 20 upvotes for this to evidence wide support for this, I'll implement his suggestion. I'd also be interested in hearing moderator's views on Paul's proposed organization in these comments; thanks

Comment: For people like me being drawn here by this weird name from the HNQ and having no idea what a penny-farthing actually is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny-farthing

Comment: The only problem with implementing @PaulH suggesting is that the an answer with the level of detail that you have already provided would become a small novel if it were to cover multiple jurisdictions. Part of the problem here is you have asked a binary question and answered it with an essay. Not that it's a bad answer - it's a very good answer but the terseness of the question mismatches it.

Comment: Looks like @Rodney has a fair point too about how PaulH's idea could create scalability issues.  Even if we only had just the EU & US, I'd imagine those answers would have a similar length as mine. Indeed, one of the guys I ride Penny-Farthings is Mexican- this is a bike with a following. So I don't doubt that Penny-Farthing enthusiasts exist in many nations that could create an answer for their own countries. Would be ideal if we could centralize this, but I agree with Rodney that maybe individual questions would be more maintainable & user-friendly. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, I think your answer is a bit too long. For instance, the parts about lights apply to all bikes, so there's no need to include it in a question asking if penny-farthings are street legal. Similar opinion about the Insurance and Brakes sections. Working backwards from your answer, a better question would be: _what are the parameters under which pedal-driven cycles legally operate?_

Comment: I understand your concerns about overlap, but in order to break up my post into things specific to PF and those _**not** specific to PFs_, we'd be assuming that a PF novice knows the questions they need to look for answers to!  My other bike is an MTB, so I knew absolutely zilch about the legal requirements for riding cycles on the roads, let alone laws PF- specific. It was a deep rabbit hole I went down trying to understand what was required to ride a PF legally. So I feel the content type is right and goal of centralizing it right, but I'll try to trim length. Hope that's a fair compromise!

Comment: @PaulH just thought about another issue implementing your suggestion: If we aggregate ALL country answer under this question, only one country would get the "accepted" answer. What if we have competing answers for the same country? Sure, folks could use upvotes to decide which to prefer, but in any event, we'd arrive at a situation where there could be no single answer that was accepted as authoritative which seems contrary to how SE is organized.  I'm definitely for centralizing all countries in one place if possible, it just seems there are scalability issues in addition to this one.

Comment: I'm newish to the group and still learning things daily...BUT...A Penny-Farthing is a bike, albeit a bike without symmetrical wheels, but nonetheless still a bike and subject to the same laws any other bike would be to be ridden on Public roads UK..

Comment: F1Linux you've asked a good question and made a great, thorough answer. Don't change the question now. @PaulH 's question is fundamentally different and should be asked as a different question if that is required

Comment: @Swifty The answer now incorporates the feedback of other users. And it's this collaboration that's responsible for the popularity- _and correctness_- it. When collaborating with others, it's my way to work towards a consensus. Despite the issues Rodney & I raised with the proposal, the consensus is clearly w/ PaulH, so I'm inclined to defer to the majority. I just feel it would be intellectually dishonest to use the user feedback that suits me and ignore that which doesn't. Democracy is a bitch I guess, but generally yields better results than an autocracy.

Comment: @PaulH Looks like your proposal prevailed: implemented it as requested-

Comment: @PaulH I implemented your proposal bud, but got overturned by Swifty who rolled-back the change I made last night: I have no admin privileges on this SE site, so nothing more I can do bud. I do try to implement user feedback wherever possible when folks are kind enough to provide it, but sometimes it's not and this is such a case.

Comment: @F1Linux That's not how the site works, please stop changing the question once it has been asked and answered, with a significant number of upvotes. You might like to accept your answer as the accepted answer, that is even encouraged. It's not democracy, it's not autocracy, it's question and answer. It would be "intellectually dishonest" to receive upvotes for an interesting question but then fundamentally change the question against the norms of the site.

Comment: @Swifty I mentioned in my response to PaulH the issue you're raising- that I felt the change was contrary to how SE worked. I even asked for feedback from the admins; none responded. Users still kept upvoting PaulH's proposals despite the reservations both Rodney and I raised.Generally, if folks are kind enough to leave feedback I try to take their views onboard and implement them where possible. SE is a community, so try to step back and take a wider view of what the community has to say. And of course I respect and appreciate your view Swifty.  I'll keep your edit bud. Thanks-

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### UNITED KINGDOM

### Intro

I ride a 50" Penny-Farthing almost daily on the UK's public roads, both individually and as part of groups in daylight and evening conditions.

Before venturing out onto the UK's roads when I began my Penny-Farthing journey, I asked myself this very question. And when people see me on my PF, many will invariably ask me: "*Is that **thing** legal to ride on the roads?!?!?*"

Initially had to piece together an understanding from a gazillion different sites. This answer hopes to centralize this research into a single comprehensive, authoritative **PEER REVIEWED** source for riding Penny-Farthings on public roads ***in the UK ONLY***. And save the reader the grief of hunting-down this information across many sources.

Please alert me to errors or omissions you may spot in the comments section and I'll revise the answer accordingly.

### SHORT ANSWER:

"***Yes***", but only if you observe all the traffic laws you're required to riding a regular "***safety***" bicycle (those odd things with symmetrical wheels) and your Penny-Farthing has the minimum safety equipment required by law (see "**LONGER ANSWER**" for specifics).

### LONGER ANSWER:

### Governing Laws on Cycling:

A Penny-Farthing is a bike, albeit a direct-drive bike without symmetrical wheels, but nonetheless still a bike and subject to the same laws as any other bicycle ridden on Public roads.

The (5) key Laws relating to bicycles - ***ALL bicycles*** - are:

- [The Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/rules-for-cyclists-59-to-82): When interpreting the Highway Code, the words ***MUST*** and ***MUST NOT*** imply a legal requirement. Anything not so qualified is advice. **HOWEVER**: If you're ever involved in an accident and find yourself in court, your failure to observe best-practice as advised in the Highway code could go against you; only a downside in not heeding advice in the Highway code if you are cycling on public roads.
- [THE HIGHWAY CODE, Northern Ireland](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/highway-code): Northern Irish Penny-Farthing Riders be guided by this.
- [The Pedal Cycles (Construction and Use) Regulations 1983](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1983/1176/pdfs/uksi_19831176_en.pdf)
- [The Road Vehicles Lighting Regulations 1989](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1989/1796/contents/made)
- [The Road Vehicles Lighting (Amendment) Regulations 2005](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2005/2559/contents/made)
- [The Pedal Cycles (Construction and Use) (Amendment) Regulations 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/474/pdfs/uksi_20150474_en.pdf)

Older Penny-Farthings manufactured before these laws were enacted can be outside of them. However, most Penny-Farthings manufactured in modern times **WILL** necessarily be subject to ALL these laws.

The guidance in this post is based on prevailing laws at the time of writing. Laws changes over time, and with the rise of "***e-Bikes***" I expect cycling laws will be revisited in the near future. Future readers are advised to give me a heads-up if anything becomes out of date and I will revise this answer accordingly.

### Obedience to ALL Traffic Laws:

Braking/stopping on a Penny-Farthing brings challenges one doesn't encounter riding a "safety" bicycle where you can put your feet on the ground at a halt. Nonetheless you still must stop at red signals, yield to traffic on your right at roundabouts and signal changes of direction. ***If you cannot perform these fundamental operations competently on a Penny-Farthing, even if your PF is appointed with all the correct equipment which is described below, you shouldn't be riding it on the public roads.***

### Brakes:

<s>Regulation 7 of [The Pedal Cycles (Construction and Use) Regulations 1983](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1983/1176/pdfs/uksi_19831176_en.pdf) defines the legal requirements for brakes on a pedal cycle. As a Penny-Farthing is a "*fixie*"- a direct-drive bicycle where only one wheel is operated by the pedals. 7(1)(b)(i) of the statute requires only a **SINGLE** braking system.</s>

**UPDATE**: I asked Roger @ unicycle.com- who is the manufacturer of the popular UDC Penny-Farthings of which I'm a rider of- to review my answer for correctness and he states that  Rule 9.1 trumps Rule 7(1)(b)(i) in respect to brakes on a "*fixie*".

> 9.(1) Nothing in Regulation 7 or 8 applies to -(a) any pedal cycle so constructed that the pedals act on any wheel or on the axle of any wheel without the interposition of any gearing or chain;

- **Front Wheel Brake**: So according to ***Regulation 9.(1)(a)***, as the the pedals of a Penny-Farthing are affixed directly to the wheel to drive it in the absence of gearing, then negative resistance on the pedals is the only braking mechanism we require.  As a practical matter, it would be ***highly*** undesirable to have a mechanical brake on a Penny-Farthing's front wheel in any event due to the risk of doing a "header" and going over the handlebars if such a brake was applied too quickly and/or aggressively.
- **Rear Wheel Brake**: Although a braking mechanism is not required by law as the small rear wheel is not driven by the pedals or gearing, Penny-Farthings **DO** have at the very least a rear brake: ***the rider's heel***. This is achieved by the rider standing on the mount peg and applying their heel to the rear wheel. This method may sound crazy, but it's proven and has been in use as a braking system by Penny-Farthing riders since the beginning. Newer, modern Penny-Farthings such as the [UDC MK 4](https://www.unicycle.co.uk/penny-farthing.html) ship with a calliper brake on the rear wheel. Nonetheless all PF riders should familiarize themselves with technique of braking the rear wheel with their heel!
- **Testing & Inspection of Braking systems by Police**: ***Regulation 11*** of the same statute provides the mechanism for the Police to inspect any cyclist's brakes are legal. Police as a general rule do not randomly stop cyclists and checking their brakes. I expect the Police will do so if you are either involved in an accident or they observe you cycling out of control.

To learn more about Penny-Farthing braking mechanisms, go [HERE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/73366/52565)

[image: Rear calliper brake on a UDC MK4 PF]
Rear calliper brake on a UDC MK4 PF

### Lights & Reflectors:

"[The Road Vehicles Lighting Regulations 1989](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1989/1796/made)" governs the lighting cyclists will be required to have. The "***Explanatory Note***" section of which details that "***sunrise***" and "***sunset***" now replace “***daytime hours***” and “***hours of darkness***” which included a half hour before each. Thanks to @thelawnet for the correction- well spotted!

I ride my Penny-Farthing frequently at night, so I not only meet the legal minimums for lights, I seriously exceed them. ;-)

- **Lights**: Lights are NOT required when cycling in daytime. HOWEVER: If riding your Penny-Farthing (or any bicycle) between <s>30 minutes **BEFORE**</s> sunset and <s>30 minutes **AFTER**</s> sunrise, it must have:

  - **Front Light STEADY**: Light must be **WHITE** in colour and emit **STEADY** light ***OR***
  - **Front Light FLASHING**: [Whether a flashing light is approved depends upon whether it has additionally has a ***steady*** mode](https://www.cyclinguk.org/lighting-regulations). If ***NOT***, a flashing light **CAN** be used ***IN LIEU OF*** a steady white light.  If your flashing light ***DOES*** have a steady mode, then it's only approved if it conforms to BS6102/3.

[image: Front lights Top view]
One flashlight set to steady the other to rapid flashing

- **Rear Light**: **RED** rear facing light affixed to it. NOTE: I bought a red rear light that incorporated a reflector in it.  So even if the batteries died while I was riding at night, the reflector would STILL work.

[image: Rear Red light closeup]
Note Rear Red Light incorporates a reflector that works even when light off

[image: Rear Red Light side view showing silicone band attachment]
The spine is too thick for most light mounts I got around the problem by using a silicone band bought on Amazon to attach; works perfectly.

[image: Silicone Band used to attach Red Lights]

- **Reflectors**:

  - **Pedals**: Required to be fitted with [amber reflectors](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1989/1796/schedule/20/made).
  - **Rear Reflector**: A **RED** rear reflector required to be placed between 250-900mm from the ground. My rear Red light incorporates a reflector, so killed two birds with one stone
  - **OPTIONAL**: I put strips of silver reflective tape up the back of my Penny-Farthing's spine. Doesn't look bad and anything I can do to increase visibility I will do.

### Bells:

I couldn't find any reference that states a bell is a legal requirement, but you'd foolish to cycle without one. And if it's true that it's a legal requirement to SELL bicycles with a bell (haven't been able to track down a link to this yet), the odds are you already have a bell anyway...

**EXCEPTION**: Northern Ireland: [a bell **IS** a legal requirement in NI](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/cycling-getting-started), unlike the rest of the UK.

### Cycling on Drink or Drugs: Highway Code Rule 68

If you toodle home from the pub pissed on your Penny-Farthing and are caught in such a condition by the Police, it can attract a £1000 fine. Although technically your vehicle license can't be endorsed with points or directly lost for cycling unfit, [you could still lose your vehicle license](https://www.cyclinguk.org/article/whats-legal-and-whats-not-your-bike).

And if you are involved in an accident, I'm sure whatever cycling insurance you have will likely be invalidated.

Who doesn't like toodling to a pub on a their Penny-Farthing for a pie and a pint? Just take care not to over-do it...

### Insurance:

Unlike a motor vehicle, cyclists are **NOT** required by law to have liability insurance. HOWEVER, strike some pedestrian who steps in front of your Penny-Farthing listening to music with their earbuds and you'll wish you did. And stopping a Penny-Farthing is a bit more challenging when responding to the presentation of a hazzard.

**Important Considerations**:

- **EXCLUSIONS to Look For**: If the policy *excludes* ***direct-drive*** cycles- ones where the wheels are not driven by gearing as with a "safety" bicycle- then your Penny-Farthing would **NOT** be covered.
- **Cycle Appointed with all Legally Required Safety Equipment**: Ensure all the lighting, braking, and other safety equipment required by law is present and working condition. If the Police inspect your Penny-Farthing (or any cycle) after an accident and anything is found amiss, I suspect an insurer will jump at the opportunity to deny you coverage.
- **Group Insurance vs Personal Policy**: Many cycling organizations offer liability insurance with certain memberships. Getting group cover via an organization is less complicated and will likely provide better cover with fewer exclusions than taking out an individual policy. Also, if you can support organizations that advocate for cyclists, why not?!?!?

I emailed ***British Cycling***- *who provides my liability insurance with my "Ride" membership*- and directly asked them:

> I ride a Penny-Farthing- which is legal to ride on the UK's public roads.  However, this is a direct-drive bicycle- the pedals are affixed to the wheel and drive it directly in lieu of gearing. Is this covered under my membership liability insurance?

They replied ***IN WRITING*** to this question that it **WAS**:

> Yes I can confirm you are covered on a penny farthing.

So now I am 100% bullet-proof if anything happens.  I'd suggest asking for such a confirmation before agreeing the policy so there's not grief later if you're involved in an accident riding your Penny-Farthing.

So I can confirm AT LEAST ***British Cycling*** DEFINITELY provide Penny-Farthing cyclists liability insurance with their "Ride" membership.

### Addition sources consulted to prepare this answer:

In addition to the other links, I've consulted the below sources:

- https://www.cyclescheme.co.uk/community/featured/cycling-and-the-law
- https://www.cyclinguk.org/article/whats-legal-and-whats-not-your-bike
- https://www.cyclinguk.org/cyclists-library/regulations/construction-use
- https://www.cyclinguk.org/lighting-regulations

Comment: I was under the impression that bells are not compulsory, but that new bikes had to be sold equipped with bells. Surprised to see reflectors are still compulsory - how many road bikes have clipless pedals which don't have reflectors attached?

Comment: @thosphor Just researched this. Although I couldn't find any law about requiring bikes to be sold with bells, I did however find out that a bell IS a legal requirement in Northern Ireland.  Thanks for making me look again!

Comment: Are fixies really road-legal in the UK? I also very much doubt that stopping the wheel with your feet counts as “brake”.

Comment: Yes, a Fixie is legal believe it or not. Indeed, Penny-Farthings are fixes-they have a direct-drive wheel- and they are legal assuming you meet the other requirements specified in this post. I’ve provided links for all my sources. I ride with groups of Penny-Farthing riders and we pass police who wave to us constantly.  I’m sure if there was any doubt, by this point I’d have been spoken to by the Police ;-) Your question proves we needed a post dealing with this issue as there is a lot of confusion about Pennys being legal to ride on public roads

Comment: Most of this is not specific to penny farthings. The lighting regulations state 'between sunset and sunrise'. There is nothing about 30 minutes for cyclists. In practice any requirements about lights being flashing/steady/bright is not enforced at all by the cops. But having a light might be. There is zero chance of the reflector regulations being enforced either.

Comment: @thelawnet Just added your correction about the 30 minutes before sunset and 30 minutes after sunrise correction.  You are indeed correct- well spotted and many thanks for pointing that out! In respect to the Police not caring about some of the minutiae (ie a missing reflector), I'm a former Police Officer (NYPD), so I agree with your observation. HOWEVER- if a cyclist is involved in an accident and somebody is injured/killed, their compliance with the law will be examined under a microscope in court after the fact.

Comment: Great answer!  In my opinion you should add a photo of yourself riding your Penny-Farthing on a public road, especially if you have a waxed mustache.

Comment: "As laws cannot be retroactively applied however, antique Penny-Farthings manufactured before these laws were enacted can be outside of them" - technically they can in the UK if they Parliament says so, as there's no Constitution to stop them.

Comment: @rclocher3 I can't imagine it's legal to possess a Penny-Farthing whilst _not_ sporting a waxed mustache‽

Comment: It is true about the minutiae, @F1Linux, however I imagine in the event of an accident it would also be questioned whether it's sensible to be riding a penny farthing at all. Lighting details are only like to be an issue if the driver claims 'SMIDSY'

Comment: Your more likely to be told to get of your bike and walk if your riding along a paved public section. I’ve been told to walk the bike along a section of the Thames River before now, most police officers will turn a blind eye to bicycles regardless of shape, condition and lights. They have more important things to do than spending 5 hours filling in paperwork for a slightly wonky light that’s situated 50mm higher than it should be or no lights at all.

Comment: @DanK The legality of ***where*** a Penny-Farthing can be ridden- that is to say one appointed with all the required equipment by the law- is the same for a regular "safety" bicycle. Whether or not it's sensible to ride Penny-Farthings on pavements is another matter ;-).  My general view is to stick to roads and leave pavements to pedestrians- _on any type of bicycle_.  A notable exception being riding my MTB along canal tow paths. Walkers do use these, but the tow paths I ride on are largely empty 99% of the time.

Comment: FYI there is no "yielding to traffic on your right at an intersection" in the UK, except at roundabouts. At an intersection without priority signs, the official rule is to "proceed with caution".

Comment: @thosphor that might be a good separate question, how clipless pedals comply with retro-reflector requirements.   Generally "grandfathering" older items into newer laws means they can be left as-is if made before the law was enacted, BUT if there's substantial rework then the new code applies.  Home electrical wiring, for example.

Comment: "Who doesn't like toodling to a pub on a their Penny-Farthing for a pie and a pint?" I've got to say that my visit to England was _far_ too short!

Comment: @FreeMan Drawing-up to a pub on a Penny-Farthing is the **ONLY** way to arrive ;-).

Comment: Please, don't have red lights facing forwards or white reflectors backward. Even if there's a loophole that doesn't make it completely illegal.

Comment: @ojs Didn't think a red reflector would interfere with driver's vision.  Anyhoo, removed the images per your guidance

Comment: It's not only about vision, but also that having red light in front gives a strong message that the person either doesn't know traffic rules or thinks they don't apply to them. Having these people around in traffic is stressful, visible or not.

Comment: @ojs My problem is drivers not paying attention and there are a lot of them out there. I even wear a ProViz jacket and they **STILL** don't see.  And being a former Police Officer with advanced driving qualifications, so I'm in a fair position to assess the driving I'm seeing on the roads as a cyclist and quite frankly, it's shockingly bad.

Comment: I think it's not about drivers not seeing you, but not recognizing what you are and how you move. People drive into traffic dividers, stopped trucks and even trains because they don't recognize what they are in time. But both as driver as cyclist, if a cyclist is riding the wrong way in my lane, I'd prefer them to not have red light in front.

Comment: PCCUR Regulation 7, or 7(1)(b)(i), does not apply to Penny Farthings, because of the explicit exemption contained in 9(1)(a)): _"Nothing in Regulation 7 or 8 applies to any pedal cycle so constructed that the pedals act on any wheel or on the axle of any wheel without the interposition of any gearing or chain"_

Comment: @bain- Roger at unicycle.com beat you too it: just updating that very change as you flagged it- keen eye!  That's why I put that I wanted the article peer reviewed.  Check back in a moment or two and it will be straight. Thanks!

Comment: UK law absolutely can be retroactively applied. A recent example would be the **Caravans Act (1991)** which was deemed to apply from 1989 onwards or the **War Crimes Act** (1991) which made war crimes in WWII applicable for criminal sanction.

Comment: @Richard Interesting- I never imagined such a thing was possible.  Will remove the part about law not being retroactively applied.  Thanks-

Comment: @F1Linux - In this instance it would be closer to say that no bicycle manufacturing laws have been enacted that apply retrospectively.

Comment: @F1Linux re: fixies and two braking systems, a very common example of fixed gear bicycles in the UK is the "normal" bikes made for very young children. Because they have a fixed gear they're only fitted with one brake lever/caliper fitted (which achieves the legal requirement for two independent braking systems).

Comment: @F1Linux It is actually an offence to display a red light to the front. From The Road Vehicles Lighting Regulations 1989. "PART II 11.—(1) No vehicle shall be fitted with a lamp which is capable of showing a red light to the front, except– "

Comment: I’ve removed the pics per @ojs earlier comments

Comment: @F1Linux It is the The Pedal Bicycles (Safety) Regulations 2010 that require new bikes to have bell fitted. "Supply of assembled bicycles 4.—(1) Subject to paragraph (2), a person must not supply a bicycle unless the requirements of paragraphs (3) to (12) of this regulation are satisfied. (3) The bicycle must be fitted with a bell which is of a category intended for use on bicycles. ". However this doesn't require one to be kept on.

Comment: @F1Linux - "a cyclist is involved in an accident and somebody is injured/killed, their compliance with the law will be examined under a microscope in court after the fact. " - There are plenty of cases, especially in NY, where that is completely untrue, and also, that should be the case when motorists kill/injure people, and that that examination rarely happens.

Comment: @whatsisname Firstly, this answer is ***exclusively*** about the UK. Secondly, I was actually a Police Officer in New York City. I can tell you if a cop is called to deal with an accident that resulted in serious injury or death, **EVERYTHING** would get looked at and charged appropriately.

Comment: I'm not from NY, but I know the words "no criminality suspected". About the red lights in front, it's not just about the pictures, but claiming to be police officer and not knowing the rules or bothering to look them up.

Comment: @ojs I'm not "claiming" to be a Police Officer- I was. In NYPD; not the UK. This post was about what I had to learn to be legal to ride on the **UK's** roads, which I ***was*** ignorant of cycling laws.  Hence all the research to understand all the laws relating to cyclists I hadn't any prior knowledge of.  As for the red light you bang-on about, I've had 2 careless motorists strike me on the UK's roads; I try to max visibility. I actioned your feedback about red lights when it was given, so unsure what your latest comment's purpose was other than to imply I was lying about being a cop...

Comment: @F1Linux This is a great answer. 
However you forget to mention that it's also illegal to "pedal furiously" (at least England & Wales, not sure about Scotland or NI) on any type of bicycle ;-) .

Comment: @Pete On a track even 20 MPH is good-going. But when cycling on roads with traffic, potholes, crosswalks, and other hazards 12-13 MPH is the best even an experience PF rider could hope to achieve. Hard to "cycle furiously" at that speed ;-).  And I believe when I've read about cyclists getting prosecuted for this, they were cycling recklessly on pavements rather than on roads.

Answer (score 0):

Inthe UK. A Penny-Farthing is a bike, albeit a bike without symmetrical wheels, ((unless your a learner with stabilisers)) But nonetheless its still a bike and subject to the same laws any other bike would be to be ridden on Public roads. That is as long as you don't pop any Wheelies or add a motorised wheel that produces more motorised speed than the EUs...15.5mph limit...